# How do I get the difference between two dates in a .csproj file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I saw some [code like this](https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2020/02/23/net-core-standard-auto-incrementing-versioning/), in a csproj file

```
$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(mmff))
```

to autoincrement the assembly version:

```
<VersionSuffix>2.0.0.$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(mmff))</VersionSuffix>
<AssemblyVersion Condition=" '$(VersionSuffix)' == '' ">0.0.0.1</AssemblyVersion>
```

What kind of language/script is that? How do I use it to get the difference between two dates?

I tried to do something like this:

```
<VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
<VersionMinor>1</VersionMinor>
<DaysFromLastRelease>$(([System.DateTime]::UtcNow - new [System.DateTime](2021,1,1))::TotalDays)</DaysFromLastRelease>
```

but it does not work :)

Comment: It is not a language.  File is only read and is XML format.

Comment: The OP is speaking of the embedded expressions like `[System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(mmff)`.

Comment: Looks a bit like PowerShell

Comment: I would not recommend using time to produce version numbers. It can break MSBuild's incremental build model and produce longer build times.

Comment: Saw this [example](https://github.com/dasMulli/dotnext-2020-samples/tree/main/04_Versioning) about semantic versioning. It uses git's commit info instead of time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.csproj` files are basically [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) files (XML). The embedded syntax you are referring to is called a [Property Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2019).

It appears that subtraction using the minus (`-`) might not be supported. There is a `Subtract()` property function in [Property Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2019).

Perhaps this could be the base for a solution. I have not tried it!

```
<Now>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.DayOfYear)</Now>

<January>$([System.DateTime]::new(2021,1,1)).DayOfYear</January>
<!-- or... (not sure about the below)
<January>$([System.DateTime]::Parse("1/1/2021").DayOfYear)</January>
 -->

<DaysFromLastRelease>$([MSBuild]::Subtract($(Now), $(January)))</DaysFromLastRelease>
```

Other possibilities

- calculate the date difference by writing an MSBuild task
- call out to a simple program you write
- somehow use an external program to set an environment variable, and then reference that variable in your `.csproj`

Comment: `new DateTime` could be used as e.g. `$([System.DateTime]::new(2021,1,1))`

Comment: @Renat good to know. I'll add to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Is this supported by any compiler of the .NET platform (Framework and/or Core, Mono...), or only dedicated to Visual Studio?

Comment: @OlivierRogier it's MSBuild, so presumably it would work outside of VS.

Comment: `DayOfAYear` will only work with 1st of January then ) if I have the first day of February will not....

Comment: @Serge sorry not following you. Maybe you don't need `<January>` at all then...?

Comment: I mean, if we put the december 2020 then it would be a negative value, because in december 2020 DayOfYear will be greater than in January or Mai 2021...

Comment: Based on the fact you have a node called `DaysFromLastRelease` it sounds like you are wanting to calculate `Now - LastBuildDate` and then get that in a # of days right? What I provided in my answer is kind of hardcoded, so that's why I said it would be a base, and not a full solution. Full solution would have to account for oddities such as a negative value. MSBuild while powerful, may have met its match in what you want to do... not sure ;)

Comment: not working of DayOfYear of the last date is less than the DayOfYear of previous date (if next year)

Answer (score 5):

That's what worked for me:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VersionMajor Condition="'$(VersionMajor)' == ''">0</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor Condition="'$(VersionMinor)' == ''">0</VersionMinor>
    <VersionPatch Condition="'$(VersionPatch)' == ''">$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Subtract($([System.DateTime]::new(2001,1,1))).TotalDays.ToString("0"))</VersionPatch>
    <VersionRevision Condition="'$(VersionRevision)' == ''">$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes.ToString("0"))</VersionRevision>
    <Version>$(VersionMajor).$(VersionMinor).$(VersionPatch).$(VersionRevision)</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here I manually set VersionMajor and VersionMinor. Then I have autoincremented values for Patch and revision.

- Patch : number of days since 2001/01/01 (first day of century XXI).
- Revision : total minutes of the day

That's good enought untill June 2180 (Remember máx versión number is 65534).

---

Extra tip:
I put all this lines into a Version.Build.props file into Properties folder. Then I import it from csproj file with this tag:

```
<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('Version.Build.props', '$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/Properties/'))" />
```

This way, I can manually set proyect versions manually in my csproj file, left them in auto or a mix of them by just setting VersionMajor and VersionMinor which is what I actually do.

Comment: I added `.Date` after UtcNow - the TotalDays implementation rounds PM to the next day, which breaks the strict increasing logic

```<VersionPatch Condition="'$(VersionPatch)' == ''">$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.Date.Subtract($([System.DateTime]::new(2001, 1, 1))).TotalDays.ToString("0"))</VersionPatch>```

Comment: I tested it and it works for me. My PC is set to use 24h format by default, maybe that's the point here.